# How do I break a long equation over lines?

Tags: latex, equation

I am trying to add an equation in a new line. The problem is that the equation is too long for the line, and I need to break it manually. Otherwise, it just overlaps to the right column, or to the right margins (and looks ugly...).
Is there a way LaTeX can brake the equation for me, so it seems nice?

I'm attaching my latex code:

```
\begin{align*}
f(n)-f(0) &= A(n)-B(n)-C(n)-D(n)\cdot d-\left(A(0)-B(0)-C(0)-D(0)\cdot d\right) \\
          &= A(n)-0-X-D(n)\cdot d-\left(0-0-0-0\right) \\
          &= A(n)-X-D(n)\cdot d
\end{align*}
```

The problematic line is the first line, which is too long.

Comment: This is not what align* is meant for: the lines are treated as separate equations, while it is (IMO) one equation. Use \[\begin{split} .... \end{split}\] in stead. This way, if you decide to number everything, the block will get one number, in stead of three.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `breqn` package is designed to split long equations automatically. It works very well in the majority of situations, but it's not as mature as the `amsmath` package. Here's how you'd write your example equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
f(n)-f(0) = A(n)-B(n)-C(n)-D(n)\cdot d-\left(A(0)-B(0)-C(0)-D(0)\cdot d\right)
          = A(n)-0-X-D(n)\cdot d-\left(0-0-0-0\right)
          = A(n)-X-D(n)\cdot d
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

Note there is no markup for alignment or newlines, but the output looks essentially the same as if you used `align`.

Comment: Wow! That one works really really good!
This fits the whole idea of Latex, of not needing to worry if your code is in a multi-column small font format, or a uni-column large font one. Thanks!

Comment: After playing around with it a little more, I see that it is not the panacea, and I'll need to use the split environment sometimes also. But this is nice anyway.

Answer (score 10):

I usually prefer to handle this by using the `amsmath` package and using the `split` structure.  There are a bunch of useful structures in there for splitting equations across lines, but that's usually the simplest to use.

Many TeX installations will already have the package, but you can also get it from [the AMS website](http://www.ams.org/tex/amslatex.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the ams website. It has some jems inside.

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach I've used in the past is an `eqnarray`. See for example [this page](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/Multiline.html).

Comment: eqnarray seems nice. I'm not sure if it is better than split or not, and why.

Comment: In fact, `align` and `align*`, the family of environments used by the OP, are the way to go when you want to use something like `eqnarray`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. When working inside a display, you are responsible for line breaks. How to line break, and how to continue on the next line in case of brackets, is a tough question for humans (check, for instance, the relevant section in Grätzer, "Math into LaTeX"), let alone for a computer.

Example:
when you break the first line after \left(, you need a \right. at the end, and \left. at the beginning of the next line (otherwise you'll get an error). Moreover, you'd want the beginning of the next line to be further right than the bracket produced by \left(

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree with that. Latex does succeed to place words and sentences within margins quite nicely. 

+1 for the begin and end split tip.

Comment: breqn actually manages to solve the problem quite well. And if/when it does go wrong, you can always break manually to suite.